# Laravel 419 unknown status

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, cross-domain, csrf

I am making an AJAX request from a subdomain to main domain. I have set up CORS so that subdomain is attached automatically to the allowed domain listing. I am getting a `419 (unknown status)` error and upon dumping the error I found out that I am getting `TokenMissmatchException`.

I noticed also that that is infact true because I also saw:

```
"_token" => "h7I07Iv0m4sF7XHhXjtygnfCtITgzCi3Ml8lfT7Z" // <-- sent
"_token" => "N118Izko7j5uf851MpijBXInFLaUVicRdf9uw3h4" // <-- in session
```

I am obviously sending token with my AJAX request as I see it in the headers section when inspecting the request.

I suppose there is some missmatch going on because I am traversing from my subdomain to my domain.

How can I align tokens across my main domain and all subdomains so that I don't get an exception?

**NOTE**

All AJAX routes are receiving a token from

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Attaching it to every request in

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

I have placed this under `session.php`

```
"domain" => "." . env('APP_URL'),
```

because of the cookies, even though honestly I'm not sure what it does

Comment: remove the csrf tokens

Comment: And expose my app to CSRF attacks?

Comment: both domain and subdomain are on the same laravel installation?

Comment: yes, domain routing is done within `web.php`

Comment: Are you delegating the event for the `ajaxSetup` after the AJAX call?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not really a front-end guru

Comment: Can you configure your session cookies to use a shared top-domain, and have the same APP_KEY for all domains? That would make them all share the same session.

Comment: They are the part of the same application, so they do share the same key. I have entered the dotted notation for cookies, isn't that it?

Answer (score 0):

Session sharing across multiple domain.....
There can be tweaks to do it. To make a cookie available in all the sub-domains you need to assign it to the root domain.

```
 session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"
```

Personally I would recommend a different approach (but it also depends on other factors upon which I don't have full visibility from your question....)

Perform the ajax call from/to the same subdomain  (CSRF middleware protected, standard CSRF usage)
On the controller perform a server to server backend call to your main domain (e.g. a curl_exec )

The server to server call is not visible and you can protect it... e.g. at network level or by adding an Oauth server if the two domain communicates through internet.